# Conflict with buttons android

Tags: java, android, button, methods

I have 2 xml files, "activity_main" and "main_screen", both have 1 button each here are the xml of the buttons:

The login button < this button is on the first screen of my application

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/entrar"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And the "save data button" < this one is on the second screen.

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salvar"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
```

Java code of the first button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Editable login = editLogin.getText();
                String loginTexto = login.toString();

                Editable pass = editPass.getText();
                String senhaTexto = pass.toString();

                try{
                    trocaTela();
                    System.out.println("botao login" + R.id.button);
                    //a.enviaDados(loginTexto, senhaTexto, textView);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
```

Java code of the second button:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText editNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomeEdit);
                final EditText editDestino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destinoEdit);
                final EditText editKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kmEdit);
                final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                //pega o texto inserido no campo da placa
                Editable editable = editPlaca.getText();
                String placaTexto = editable.toString();

                //pega o nome inserido no campo do nome
                Editable nomeEditable = editNome.getText();
                String nomeTexto = nomeEditable.toString();

                //pega o destino inserido no campo do destino
                Editable destinoEditable = editDestino.getText();
                String destinoTexto = destinoEditable.toString();

                //pega o valor inserido no campo do km
                Editable kmEditable = editKm.getText();
                String kmTexto = kmEditable.toString();

                try {
                    ScreenFunctions f = new ScreenFunctions();
                    System.out.println("botao screen:" +  R.id.button2);
                    f.formatPost(nomeTexto, placaTexto, destinoTexto, kmTexto, textView);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Button press exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is... i can't understand how i'll treat the "onClick" function, because the "onClick" method is abstract, so i can't change it's name, how could the second button use the MainScreen onClick and the first button use the MainActivity onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

You dont need to have this cause you are setting onclicklisteners in your java code

give me info if this helped or not

**EDIT**

make sure you have catch your button variables correctly:

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2;
```

Comment: It removed the error, but the second button is calling the first "onClick" method, that's the problem, i need it to call the second one. I can't see how this is happenning, the clickListener is inside the button2.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of function:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

to

```
android:onClick="someMethod"
```

Comment: I can't because both buttons are created inside the "onCreate" method, i need it to call the onClick INSIDE the onCreate.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869871/how-to-catch-a-click-event-on-a-button link ... hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Remove the android:onClick="onClick" in your xml files.
You are misunderstand the usage of android:onClick tag in xml file.
Please check [the document of android:onClick tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to make your code prettier and better, you should use **ButterKnife** for view injection and specifying the onclick method with that, like this:

1.) add ButterKnife to your dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
```

2.) inject your view into the field

```
@InjectView(R.id.button)
public Button button;
```

3.) specify the onClick method

```
@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void myOnClickMethod(View view)
{
    //do things
}
```

4.) inject the activity or fragment with ButterKnife

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    ...
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
    ...
    return rootView;
}
```